# Ajax response ? how to minimize ajax requests in a game

Tags: php, ajax

I am building a poker game via html/php/ajax (and some other stuff) NO-FLASH . 
I have little experience in programming games , so i have small question !

assuming ur playing poker , how your browser will know that some player threw a card ?
shall my browser send ajax request to know if somebody made a move ??? or is there anyway to treat ajax->php like a socket ajax<->php ??

I hope someone understands my question , thanks

Comment: Search for the term `WebSocket`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the amount of traffic you'll, face, a good idea is to use a Message Queue server, such as [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) along with something to allow *all*  browsers to connect to ActiveMQ and receive 'push' messages from it, on the lines of [Orbited 2](http://labs.gameclosure.com/orbited2/) - this one is prepared for changes on the websocket protocol as new reviews are generated (not sure a consensus over the protocol has been reached yet).

The best bet for you is to research a relatively old technology, but not widely used (I mean, when compared to Ajax) that is known both as [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) and [Ajax Push](http://www.google.com.br/search?q=Ajax+Push).

It's obvious there are several other implementations, such as [APE](http://www.ape-project.org/), and you would probably want to pick the one (whose programming language and/or API) you feel mostly comfortable with.